# Autodetect json-schema.org for a json/yaml file?

Tags: json, yaml, jsonschema

I am looking at this file:

```
---
# CI E2E test test configuration scenario using locally build images and manifests for:
# - cluster-api
# - bootstrap kubeadm
# - control-plane kubeadm
# - hetzner

# For creating local dev images run make e2e-image from the main CAPH repository
images:
  - name: ghcr.io/syself/caph-staging:${TAG:=e2e}
    loadBehavior: mustLoad
providers:
  - name: cluster-api
    type: CoreProvider
    versions:
      - name: v1.3.5
        value: "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api/releases/download/v1.3.5/core-components.yaml"
        type: "url"
        contract: v1beta1
        files:
          - sourcePath: "../data/shared/v1beta1/metadata.yaml"
        replacements:
          - old: "imagePullPolicy: Always"
            new: "imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent"
          - old: "--enable-leader-election"
            new: "--enable-leader-election=false"
          - old: --metrics-addr=127.0.0.1:8080
            new: --metrics-addr=:8080

...
```

[Source](https://github.com/syself/cluster-api-provider-hetzner/blob/main/test/e2e/config/hetzner-ci.yaml)

Above file is just an example. I an interested in the general approach.

I would like to know the [json-schema](//json-schema.org) of this file.

I want to detect if there is a matching schema already around for this structure.

Is there a way to auto-detect the json schema?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to generate a JSON Schema from the data or you want to detect if there is a matching schema already around for this structure?

Comment: @Clemens I want to detect if there is a matching schema already around for this structure.

Comment: Not I am aware of. This would also be quite challenging. Sometimes a matching schema is selected by a file name pattern (VS Code is doing this).

Comment: It would have to have a library of many schemas and validate the instance against them all to determine which ones match the data.  That seems like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The "official" shared repository if json schemas is https://www.schemastore.org/json/ . This is what VSCode and IntelliJ use as well. You can look around if its API supports your usecase or does it help anyhow.